# examine library (.cma) signature from console

Tags: ocaml

Say I have an OCaml library file foo.cma. Is there a command line tool to print the signature of the functions and other types defined there ? The ocamlbrowser utility seems to be windows-based (complains about the $DISPLAY environment variable). The use case is that I am doing a:

```
ocamlc -c foo.cma main.ml
```

and get:

```
File "main.ml", line 13, characters 33-47:
Error: Unbound value ListUtil.split
```

ListUtil.split ought to reside in foo.cma but I don't know a console-based tool to verify it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On Debian/Ubuntu, you have "ocamlobjinfo":

```
ocamlobjinfo stdlib.cma
```

will display all the unit names included in stdlib.cma. Then, you can create a short file:

```
include SomeModule
```

and compile it with -i to see what is defined in module SomeModule.

Answer (score 5):

In the toplevel, I just load the cma file:

```
#load "foo.cma";;
```

Then I re-defined a module just to see the signature:

```
module Chunk = Foo;;
```

Comment: Yep, that's useful, however it assumes that one knows the names of the modules compiled together in the cma file. For instance, if I have a file foo.cma with two separate modules in there, say foo1 and foo2, compiled like: `ocamlc -a foo1.cmo foo2.cmo -o foo.cma` then is there a way to obtain a listing of all modules found in the .cma file or does one have to know there names in advance? Seems strange in any case that a console utility is not provided out of the box.

Comment: With the toplevel method, you can see all modules in the cma file. To know the module in advance, you have to check in the mli file or if there isn't, in the source file. Otherwise, I don't know really know how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

In order to compile the code referencing `ListUtil.split` the compiler needs to find the corresponding `listUtil.cmi` file. In order to link that code compiler will need the cma (or cmo) file containing the implementation. See http://mirror.ocamlcore.org/caml.inria.fr/pub/ml-archives/caml-list/2008/09/2bc9b38171177af5dc0d832a365d290d.en.html for some explanation.